# fetch documents from mongodb collection by querying nested dictionary in mongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a collection having schema

```
{user_id:user id, user_details: {name: {age: {profession: {salary: amount}}}}}
```

sample entry is:

```
{user_id:001, user_details: {
                             abc:{21:{teacher:{salary:10000}, 
                                      book-seller:{salary:10000}}, 
                                  34:{farmer:{salary:5000}}}, 
                             xyz:{40:{manager:{salary:200000},
                                      asst_manager:{salary:198900}}}
                            }
}
{user_id:002, user_details: {
                             abc:{19:{student:{salary:1000}, 
                                      book-seller:{salary:10000}}, 
                                  34:{farmer:{salary:5000}}}, 
                             xyz:{45:{manager:{salary:200000},
                                      asst_manager:{salary:198900}}}
                            }

}
```

is there a way to query all documents in which user name is 'abc' ?

Comment: Yes, but your schema is going to be very awkward to query and update.  Don't use document field names to contain non-static data, that's what values are for.

Comment: @its-me, this example docs are completely unreadable and is not valid

Comment: @JohnnyHK I can't change the schema, this schema is currently in use at many places in our project.Can you just confirm me that there is no straight way of finding all documents for a specific user name?

Comment: If you can change your schema, do so. @JohnnyHK is right: keys should come from your application. Values can come from the outside world.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using pymongo:

```
key = 'user_details.{username}'.format(username='abc')
db.collections.find({key: {'$exists': True}})
```

This uses the [`$exists`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/exists/#op._S_exists) operator to find based on a key.

You will have to dynamically generate the 'key' variable per username.

Comment: It gives all documents for user abc, but it returns complete document not only the sub document containing user abc. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`$exists`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/exists/#op._S_exists) operator and dot notation to do this, but you need to build up your query dynamically like this (in the shell):

```js
var user = 'abc';
var query = {};
query['user_details.' + user] = { $exists: true };
db.coll.find(query);
```